# AngularJS Share data between Controllers when variable is set on another Controller

Tags: angularjs

I need to share data between two controller (controller A and controller B). I have a service in place to share the data. This works and controllerB can see the value that controllerA sets if I'm setting the value of the shared variable using "ng-model=shared.id" from the view, however; if I set the shared variable inside of the controllerA, then controllerB doesn't see it.

```
     app['controller']('controllerA', ['shared', function(shared){

          //ControllerB will not see this for some reason, unless I set
          //the value from the view using the ng-model=shared.id attribute.
          shared['id'] = "123";   

     }]);

     app['controller']('controllerB', ['shared', function(shared){

         this['someId'] = shared['id'];   

     }]);
```

Comment: Well - you have to re-assign it! You're not passing a reference to the service value - you're passing it as is at that time.

Comment: I don't understand "passing it as is at the time". Should I create another variable this['id'] = "123" then assign that to shared variable (shared['id'] = this['id'])

Comment: See the answer below - basically - when you update the shared variable, anything using that variable also needs to be updated, the changes aren't picked up automatically. Meaning in controller be - you have to recall `this['someId'] = shared['id'];` when the shared variable updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will change the service value without any issues. But the issue is controllerB won't be aware of the value change as there is no $digest cycle called.

When you change the value of `$scope` model, $digest loop will fire and the change carried forward to controllerB.

You can try as below,

```
app['controller']('controllerA', ['$scope', 'shared', function($scope, shared){
          $scope.shared = shared;
          //ControllerB will not see this for some reason, unless I set
          //the value from the view using the ng-model=shared.id attribute.
          $scope.shared['id'] = "123";    // This will trigger the $digest cycle

     }]);

     app['controller']('controllerB', ['shared', function(shared){

         this['someId'] = shared['id'];   

     }]);
```

Comment: @drivers34 Great :-)

Answer (score 0):

When the shared data is updated in the service object from one Controller the other Controller cannot know it automatically, there has to be some way to convey such as "***Hey, I've updated the shared data if anybody is using it please go ahead and fetch the updated data***", this can be done using events in AngularJS by using `$broadcast, $on, $emit` functions on the `$scope` object and on the `$rootScope` service.

Check the below example using `$broadcast` function on the `$rootScope` to invoke an event (such as the shared id got changed) on all the child scopes (i.e. broadcast will send a message to all the child scopes), the child scopes interested in an event will listen for that event using the `$on` function.

```js
angular
  .module('demo', [])
  .controller('ControllerA', ControllerA)
  .controller('ControllerB', ControllerB)
  .factory('shared', shared);

ControllerA.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'shared'];

function ControllerA($rootScope, shared) {
  var vm = this;
  shared.id = 123;
  vm.id = shared.id;
  vm.updateId = updateId;

  function updateId(id) {
    shared.id = id;
    $rootScope.$broadcast('idChanged');
  }
}

ControllerB.$inject = ['$scope', 'shared'];

function ControllerB($scope, shared) {
  var vm = this;
  vm.id = shared.id;
  $scope.$on('idChanged', idChanged);

  function idChanged(event) {
    vm.id = shared.id;
  }
}

function shared() {
  var service = {
    id: 0
  };

  return service;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo">
  <div ng-controller="ControllerA as ctrlA">
    Controller A: {{ctrlA.id}}
    <input type="text" name="id" ng-model="ctrlA.id" ng-change="ctrlA.updateId(ctrlA.id)" />
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="ControllerB as ctrlB">
    Controller B: {{ctrlB.id}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, learned a lot from your response...It caused me to dig a little deeper and find out more about this.